# Left-to-right evaluation of expression versus operator precedence. why does left-to-right evaluation appear to win out?

Tags: java

Consider this code:

```
public class Incrdecr {

static int x = 3;
static int y = ++x * 5 / x-- + --x;

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("x is " + x);
    System.out.println("y is " + y);
}
```

It evaluates to the following:

```
x is 2
y is 7
```

This makes perfect sense, but let's take a quick look at the operator precedence table:

[image]

According to this, postfix operators are supposed to be evaluated first. Now, if we go back to our code, we will see that `x--` should have been evaluated first, yet it wasn't. What am I not accounting for?

In other words, if we strictly follow the operator precedence table, then the expression would evaluate to:

`y = ++x * 5 / 3 + --x;`

which, of course, gives us an entirely different result for `y`.

Comment: Postfix operations don't take effect until the next statement. And you've modified `x` multiple times in the *current* statement. Thus you've modified the value before it was set.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch :

I do understand that my expression evaluates to:

_4 * 5 / 4 + 2_.

So, what post-fix and prefix do isn't a cause of confusion for me. What is anomalous to me is the precedence table suggests that `x--` should have been evaluated first. Which means that `x--` should be 3, instead according to that logic and not 4, as per left-to-right evaluation.

Comment: The precedence tells you nothing about evaluation order. Popularly speaking it tells you where parentheses are implied. This is not the same thing.

Comment: The point in postfix `--` is exactly that it is only perforned *after* the value of the variable has been taken.

Comment: And you are correct, this expression is (and should be) evaluated left to right.

Comment: @OleV.V. So if I'm understanding you correctly, the "precedence table" is only useful when parenthesis are involved? And in any other expression, it's simply read left-to-right and I can forget about the table?

Comment: It is evaluated in the order of precedence.  That operation simply does not affect x for the evaluation when being performed though.  After the line is completed, it affects x.

Comment: @user681574

If we go by operator precedence, then the expression would evaluate to:

`y = ++x * 5 / 3 + --x;`

Which, of course, gives us a different result for `y`.

Comment: What you have written is equivalent to `static int y = (((x + 1) * 5) / (x + 1)) + --x;`.

Comment: @EbonyMaw, the precedence table tells you that 2 - 3 * 4 is understood as 2 - (3 * 4) (not (2 - 3) * 4). So you may say it’s the other way around: the precedence table tells us what happens when we *don’t* use explicit parentheses to control the evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that your expression is evaluated left to right. This is the general evaluation order in Java (there are probably exceptions).

I think you have figured out what really happens:

1. `x` is incremented from 3 to 4 and its new value, 4, taken
2. 5 is evaluated as 5
3. 4 * 5 = 20
4. The value of `x`, 4, is taken for the division; the division yields 5 and x is decremented to 3.
5. `x` is further decremented to 2 before its value is taken for the final addition, which then yields 7.

Except: the compiler is allowed to swap steps only if it can guarantee that the result is the same. Therefore we know the result can only be 7.

Try to keep two concepts apart: evaluation order and operator precedence. They are not the same.

The precedence table tells you that the expression is understood as `((++x) * 5 / (x--)) + (--x)` (that’s mostly good because `++(x * 5 / x)-- + --x` would not make sense anyway).

To take a different example: `f(x) - g(x) * h(x)`. The mehtods are called left to right: `f()`, then `g()` and `h()` last. The precedence table only tells you that the multiplication is done before the subtraction.

EDIT: Lew Bloch in a comment questioned that `x` would be evaluated to 4 at any point during calculation. To test this, I made the following variant of your program from the question:

```
public class Incrdecr {

    static int x = 3;
    static int y = p(++x) * 5 / p(x--) + p(--x);

    private static int p(int i) {
        System.out.println("p(): " + i);
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("x is " + x);
        System.out.println("y is " + y);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
p(): 4
p(): 4
p(): 2
x is 2
y is 7
```

So yes, at two points `x` is evaluated to 4.

Comment: This is good: "... keep two concepts apart: evaluation order and operator precedence. They are not the same."

Comment: The evaluation of the post-increment occurs before the left-to-right evaluation of the pre-decrement and pre-increment operators, because the order of precedence mandates that it be evaluated first. The analysis in this answer is not correct. Just as the word "precedence" denotes, the higher-precedence operations precede those of lower precedence, contrary to what is stated in this answer.

Comment: @LewBloch, is `a` is 1 initially, what result would you expect from `++a * a--`? I expect 4. You may also see my edit of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html

Post increment/decrements follow left to right associativity of operators.

Pre increment/decrements follow right to left associativity of operators.

That is to say:
static int y = ++x * 5 / x-- + --x;

(x--) is stored as the current value of x (3) and then the rest is evaluated.

++x is evaluated to x=(x+1) forcing the evaluation of the post-increment because it is an assignment so it becomes (3) then --x is evaluated to x=(x-1) or 2.

This is functionally equivalent:
y = (x=x+1) * 5 / x-- + (x=x-1) (and it will run like this in your Java code)

The resulting equation is:

3 * 5 / 3 + 2.